# SwiftUI how to implement VKPinCodeView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have installed VKPinCodeView dependencies in my SwiftUI project however I could not implement this in my view file, and I could not find any documentation anywhere for VKPinCodeView. Here is the repo:
https://github.com/Sunspension/VKPinCodeView

import VKPinCodeView

RegisterOTPView.swift

```
struct RegisterOTPView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VKPinCodeView()
        }
    }
}
```

In the repo it is only mentioned:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
        
   let pinView = VKPinCodeView()
   pinView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.addSubview(pinView)
   pinView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
   pinView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
   pinView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
   pinView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
   pinView.onSettingStyle = { UnderlineStyle() }
   pinView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

If I am not mistaken this is for storyboard architecture, how do I use this in SwiftUI? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VKPinCodeView` is a `UIView`, so you can't use it directly in SwiftUI. It has to be wrapped inside a `UIViewRepresentable`.

Here would be the minimal setup:

```
struct VKPinCodeViewWrapper : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> VKPinCodeView {
        let view = VKPinCodeView()
        view.onSettingStyle = { UnderlineStyle() } //taken from your example code
        view.becomeFirstResponder() //taken from your example code
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: VKPinCodeView, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}

struct RegisterOTPView: View {
    var body: some View {
           VKPinCodeViewWrapper()
    }
}
```

I haven't used this particular library, so there may be things that you need to consider or change about what's set in `makeUIView` vs done in `updateUIView` like becoming the first responder.  Could take some experimentation.

More reading on UIViewRepresentable: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-wrap-a-custom-uiview-for-swiftui

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Or maybe do you have any other recommendation for achieving OTP pin input view?

Comment: It works that the underline pin view appear, but when typed, it appears blank, there is no number appearing at the input

Comment: I just updated my example to remove the `ScrollView` I had taken from your original code.  There's no need for it here and it was causing the view to be pushed outside of the scope.  I just tested on the simulator and this updated code works fine for me.